# ColdFusion parsing JSON with non-standard chars

Tags: json, coldfusion

I am able to call an API that returns a JSON response.
I convert the JSON to a CF variable but since the Response include non standard chars I can not access the structure to get the details to bind back.

[image: JSON RESPONSE]

I need to get the Job Posting Value from this structure.
Not sure the best way to access that data.

Thanks 
Matt

Comment: What do you mean by "non-standard"? And what version of CF? And how did you call the API and convert to CF?

Comment: I can pulling the JSON back and converting it to a CF value using the DeserializeJSON function.  The problem is that the inner structure has : in the naming and CF bombs out when I try to connect to get the ID and jobposting value out of this response - not sure if I can just search for that value pair

Comment: What were you using to contact your API? How do you call it?

Comment: I use a function to isolate that (ColdFusion 2018). `<cfset myKey = StructFindKey(myData,"urn:li:simpleJobPostingTask:d2a30d4e-929b-whatever","all")>`  Then you can loop through that.

Comment: What are you using to contact your API? A ColdFusion call? Or are you doing it some other way and then feeding your JSON back into CF? What JSON object is your API returning?

Comment: You can access any keys using the struct's bracket notation. Instead of `results.urn:li:simpleJobPostingTask:uuid.jobPosting`, use `results["urn:li:simpleJobPostingTask:uuid"].jobPosting`.

Comment: I'm mainly curious if the image above is your actual return value from the JSON or if that's a CF struct you've built. Are you trying to get the value of the `jobPosting` key in your inner struct, or are you trying to parse out the value of `jobPosting:12345678` so that you get `12345678`.

Comment: Your `results` struct key and the value's inner struct `id` are the same. That's why I asked what actual JSON you are getting back. Converting it to a CF variable may have created more work that could be done much more simply. Can there be multiple records in the `results` struct?

Answer (score 1):

You can either get the list of keys using `structKeyList` or you can loop over the collection of results and create new variables as needed:

```
<cfset foo = {
    errors = {},
    results = {
        "urn:li:simpleJobPostingTask:some-long-uuid" = {
            id = "urn:li:simpleJobPostingTask:some-long-uuid",
            jobPosting = "urn:li:jobPosting:12345",
            status = "SUCCEEDED"
        }
    },
    statuses = {}
}>

<cfloop collection="#foo.results#" item="key">
    <!--- Do your thing per key --->
</cfloop>
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use the structKey function in Coldfusion to directly access the struct key. Incidentally, the response struct key name is identical to the response ID.

```
<!--- first we need a test struct to work with --->
<cfscript>
// init some variables
testStruct=structNew();
resultStruct=structNew();
tempStruct=structnew();

// create our struct keys and set a value
tempStruct['id']='ur:li:simpleJobPostingTask:d230xyz';
tempStruct['jobPosting']='urn:li:JobPosting:1234abc';
tempStruct['status']='SUCCESS';

// build our final fake struct
resultStruct=tempStruct;
testStruct['results']['ur:li:simpleJobPostingTask:d230xyz']=resultStruct;
</cfscript>
```

[image: Our Test Case]

Our final solution looks like this:

```
<!--- Here is the code you are looking for --->
<cfset firstkey=structKeyArray(testStruct.results)[1] />

<!--- dump the results --->
<cfdump var="#testStruct.results[firstkey]#" />
```

Ultimately, your code could look like this:

```
<cfdump var="#testStruct.results[structKeyArray(testStruct.results)[1]]#">
```

[image]